# Nav bar not centering

Tags: html, css

I have a footer and I’m trying to center a `<nav>` bar in the middle.

I used `margin: 0 auto;` but it’s not working. I know that I can use `position: absolute` or `relative` but I would rather not use those.

```css
footer {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

footer nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

footer ul {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

footer ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  position: relative;
  right: 50%;
}

footer ul li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">My Story</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Listings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your web page, thanks.

Comment: How is the menu not centered?

Comment: It's showing center.

Comment: You mean, that you're trying to center it vertically?

Comment: To start with, **remove all the floats**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really have a bit too much CSS there...

One important thing for solving your problem is to *not* use `display: inline-block` and any `float` on the same element (`float` prevents centering).

If you use `display: inline-block`  on the `li` items and `text-align: center` on their container (the `ul`), that basically solves the problem.

But I also erased quite a bit of your original CSS which is not necessary - see snippet below.

```css
footer {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

footer ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 20px;
}

footer ul li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">My Story</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Listings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Flex:

```
footer {
  background-color: black;
}

footer nav {
  height: 300px;
}

footer ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

footer ul li {
  padding: 30px 20px;
}

footer ul li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: ...but don't forget to prefix your flexbox https://autoprefixer.github.io